# CSS Selector for matching sub-element but applying to parent

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've been reading that there is no such thing in css like a parent selector: https://css-tricks.com/a-use-case-for-a-parent-selector/

Also mentioned here: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

However, I don't want to use JS for this use-case and need to apply `display:none` to the parent element (the child is not enough) - only if the data-path of the child ends with `.png`:

[image: element to filter]

### What I've tried:

This works only for the child element (the parent is not even mentioned):

```css
div[data-path$='.png'] {
    display: none;
}
```

Same thing here as expected:

```css
.nav-file div[data-path$='.png'] {
    display: none;
}
```

I also tried the has-selector, but it didn't work either:

```css
.nav-file:has(div[data-path$='.png']) {
    display: none;
}
```

The style has to be applied to the `.nav-file`-Object and not the child - any ideas?

*Used Browser: Electron / Obsidian --> Chromium*

Comment: Your CSS with the :has works for me on current versions of Edge/Chrome on Windows10. but not all browsers support :has, see https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas